# How to change the resolution of my desktop?

Tags: resolution, screen

In my monitor preferences, the maximum resolution is 1024x768. But I still want to increase the system resolution(to for e.g. 1600x900 or 1440x900).

Comment: That sounds like a bug, and not like something related to Unity...?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at this link and then edit your question adding more detail? http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Comment: do you have the right drivers installed? and what kind of graphics do you have? is it a laptop, a desktop, a paper plane? - this kind of information will help you get an answer.

Comment: I'm a pretty advanced user and I find that sometimes, its easier to re-install my OS , than it is to try to hack the X window settings or rely on a driver update that is "claimed" to work.

Comment: What is the make and model of your monitor. This might be a common problem of that specific monitor?

Answer (score 2):

Your monitor might not be capable of going up to those resolutions with the current drivers.  Check your hardware drivers by looking for proprietary drivers.  Also, please edit your question to include what system you're running, such as 10.04 vs. 10.10, Desktop vs. Laptop, etc.

Answer (score 0):

the monitor must has be exactly as a resolution.

But the simply solution, you can buy the monitor gain the resolution, but not for the laptop, that's may not probably help to gain the resolution.